# Order not preserved multiple tabs

Tags: javascript

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2LUl.jpg)

Hi Everyone,

Problem Description: Multiple URLs when opened in tabs , they lose the order in which they were declared in html file.

Issue :  SLOW-SERVER1 never gets to first tab.  it goes to end . the tabs are opened in this order :{  F1,F2,F3,F4,F5, S1, S2 }

Can someone advise me how to deal with this ? I am not from UI background and need help.

Thank you .

```html
<html>
    <script>
           function openLink(link){
             window.open (link.getAttribute('href'),'_blank'); 
             window.focus();
           }
           function openLinks(){
              links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 
              delay=1000
              for (i=0;i<links.length;i++)
                  { 
                    console.log(links[i]); 
                    setTimeout(openLink.bind(null,links[i]), delay); 
                    delay=delay+5000
                  }
             }
    </script>
    <body onload="openLinks()">
        <a href="https://SLOW-SERVER1">S1</a> 
        <a href="https://SLOW-SERVER2">S2</a> 
        <a href="https://FAST-SERVER1">F1</a> 
        <a href="https://FAST-SERVER2">F2</a> 
        <a href="https://FAST-SERVER3">F3</a> 
        <a href="https://FAST-SERVER4">F4</a> 
        <a href="https://FAST-SERVER5">F5</a> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Think it might depend on the browser. After removing the syntax errors I had the following behaviour: In Chrome51, The F1 tabs opens between the orginal tab and the S1 tab, consistent with your findings. In IE11, the tabs all open in the order you defined, so the F1 tab gets opened after the S2 tab in the tabs bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **EDIT** - Updating answer to reflect answer in comments:

You might be a victim of Tab Grouping. See if disabling Tab Grouping has any effect.

**How to disable IE Tab Grouping**

1. Open up Internet Options

   [image: Opening IE Settings]
2. On the General Tab, under section Tabs, click Tabs button

   [image: Opening tabs settings]
3. Under the Tabbed Browsing section, uncheck the "Enable Tab Groups*" setting and hit OK.

   [image: Disabling tab groups]

Hope this helps.

### **ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

You can use a recursive function to guarantee that the links are opened up in the proper order, regardless of load times.

```html
<html>
<script>
    function openLinksRecurse(linkStack) {
        if (linkStack == null || linkStack.length == 0) return;
        window.open(linkStack.pop().getAttribute('href'),'_blank'); 
        window.focus();
        openLinksRecurse(linkStack);
    }

    function openLinks() {
        links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 
        linkStack = new Array();
        for (var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            console.log(links[i]);
            linkStack.push(links[i]);
        }
    
        //Trigger recursive call
        openLinksRecurse(linkStack);
    }
</script>
<body onload="openLinks()">
    <a href="https://SLOW-SERVER1">S1</a> 
    <a href="https://SLOW-SERVER2">S2</a> 
    <a href="https://FAST-SERVER1">F1</a> 
    <a href="https://FAST-SERVER2">F2</a> 
    <a href="https://FAST-SERVER3">F3</a> 
    <a href="https://FAST-SERVER4">F4</a> 
    <a href="https://FAST-SERVER5">F5</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Recursion made no difference. Final order at browser IE11 is still {F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,S1,S2}. Any other advise ?

Comment: You might be a victim of **Tab Grouping**. See if disabling Tab Grouping has any effect.

Info:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/products/internet-explorer
https://www.winhelp.us/internet-explorer-11-tabs.html

Comment: Thanks . that was the issue .